# How can I sort non-English strings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, utf-8, character-encoding

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gujarati` (
  `name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `gujarati` (`name`) VALUES
('ક'),
('દિનેશ'),
('ખા'),
('ગા'),
('થા'),
('થ'),
('કા'),
('મયૂર'),
('છત્ર'),
('ત્ર'),
('ક્ષ'),
('તા'),
('એક'),
('બોલ્ડ'),
('જ'),
('ટી'),
('મી'),
('હા'),
('યા'),
('ના'),
('ધી'),
('સો'),
('લા'),
('ઝા'),
('ણ્ણા');
```

This is my table that stores the Gujarati language. How can I sort this data in a MySQL database?

Answer (score 3):

Set the `gujarati`'s table collation to the one coresponding to this language, then simply sort with `ORDER BY` - it's supposed to work out of the box

Comment: Never seen a special collation for gujarati :) But I think the default `utf8_unicode_ci` (which is used in this example) is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this meta tag :

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

And use this code in php :

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
```