# Inserting Gujarati text into a MySQL tables results in junk characters and unreadable text

Tags: mysql, database, language-agnostic, fonts, mysql-error-1064

I have three MySQL tables and I'm inserting Gujarati content into them. When I insert two tables, they're inserted fine and are readable but in one table, it is showing junk characters/unreadable text. How can I fix this?

Comment: is the datatype of column is same as that of other two columns?

Comment: if you wish , you may contact the owner of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664831/mysql-sorting-non-english-string question regarding your problem.

Answer (score 8):

MySQL has [per-table character set settings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-table.html).

You can check which character set you are using for each table - see [How do I see what character set a MySQL database / table / column is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-database-table-column-is-in-mysql).

If that is your problem, you might be able to covert the table in question, using:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Thank you my friend you saved my day.. Changing from PhpmyAdmin Panel was not working, Firing query worked at last.

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to like ...

in Your Mysql DataBase Table..
Just Change 'Collation' of column Name.
To 'utf8mb4_general_ci'.

and you can store any Gujarati font in database